# Setting default RecordType on the permission set

Tags: profile, permissions, record-type, permission-sets, field-level-security

I am trying to use permission sets to dictate what record type people have.  *The idea is I only assign one record type per permission set*.  So when a user creates a record they don't get the record selection screen

The problem is I have to set a default record type on the profile.  If I set it to MASTER then if I only have one record type on the permission set it will skip the record type selection screen (good) but default to MASTER and ignores the permission set (bad).  It appears that these need to have 1 non-master record type on the profile otherwise it skips past that screen from the permission set.

It appears that all of this needs to be done on the profile level for 1 record type on a permission set.

```
**Example:** 

Profile:  gets record and type master (which is default)
Permission set:  gets record type 1

Result: Create record
skips screen to select record type (good)
creates record of type **master** (bad)

Expected: 
skips screen to select record type
creates record of type **1**
```

**UPDATE 1:**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=permissions_record_type_access.htm&type=5

> You can assign the --Master-- record type in profiles. In permission
>   sets, you can assign only custom record types. The behavior for record
>   creation depends on which record types are assigned in profiles and
>   permission sets.
>
> If users have this record type on their profile...    And this total
>   number of custom record types in their permission sets... When they
>   create a record...
>
> --Master--    None    The new record is associated with the Master record type
>   --Master--    One The new record is associated with the custom record type. Users can’t select the Master record type.
>   --Master--    Multiple    Users are prompted to select a record type. Custom  One or more Users are prompted to select a record type. In
>   their personal settings, users can set an option to use their default
>   record type and not be prompted to choose a record type.

My issue appears to be that Visualforce is skipping this record type selection screen (no matter how many selections I have) and then is not updating the picklist.

If I switch the view to the standard page, it works as expected.  So it's not a permissions set issue, it's a visualforce issue.

Comment: You can't specify a default record type on a permission set (what would the system choose if you have multiple defaults?). That aside, it sounds like you might need to log a bug--if the user has any record types assigned, it should be allowing them to select one (if more than one), or defaulting to the only one (if they only have one option). All that said, I believe you'll probably get back a "WAD" (Working As Designed) response from support, but you may as well ask.

Comment: I’ll give it a shot.  We are definitely going for the 1 record type for a permission set strategy in order to bypass the selection screen.  It’s unfortunate if I do have to do this on the profile level for 1 record type.  In my case, it’s simply not possible based on how we have our communities structured.  I was so delighted to comment out all of my apex and visualforce/JavaScript to configure this...

Comment: Any chance that VF is skipping the rec type selection page because that's what you specified when overriding the "New" action? Also have a look at https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_recordtype.htm, maybe it's something that will be done this way better than via profiles & perm sets. Although no idea if there's API access to these preferences.

Comment: How can I override it in the New action? I'm not seeing that functionality. 
@sfdcfox

I have a new question here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193438/record-type-not-coming-over-as-parameter-on-new-to-visualforce-page

Comment: @eyescream it has something to do with the New Action.  Although, I have it set vanilla.  Check out my follow up:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193438/record-type-not-coming-over-as-parameter-on-new-to-visualforce-page

Comment: Have a closer look at what is being passed. I remember some funky stuff happening with 15 vs 18-char long IDs, record type names being not recognised, picklist values not reacting... Some Strings that had to be cast to ID or back in the apex controller... Sorry I don't remember it better, it's been a while and I don't work for this company anymore.

Comment: @sfdcfox more developments:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193581/record-type-not-found-in-controller-until-after-save

Answer (score 0):

There is something with my visualforce page that is not showing the record type on NEW and therefore is not filtering the picklist.  The record types are being saved because I can see them on the edit page and detail pages.

So the answer is, the permission sets are working as expected and the help article I posted above is correct.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=permissions_record_type_access.htm&type=5

Here is a follow up as to why the Visualforce is not being updated "On New"

[Record type not coming over as parameter on new to Visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193438/record-type-not-coming-over-as-parameter-on-new-to-visualforce-page)