# Record type not found in controller until after save

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, record-type

I am using record types to filter a picklist.  The issue I'm running into is my visualforce page will not display **ON NEW** the record type no matter what I do.  I'm using the syntax `{!myObject.recordtype.name}` and also check Apex.  The record type saves and shows properly on the standard page, the detail screen, and the edit page.

In my Apex controller on NEW record, if I put

```
system.debug(myObject.RecordType.name) //I get null on NEW
```

But when I put do that on the edit screen

```
system.debug(myObject.RecordType.name) //I get my record type on the debug log
```

Because the record type is on the screen in the edit page, the picklist filters.  *Because it's not on the NEW page, the picklist will not filter.*

**I cannot get access to the assigned record type on new**

**NEW PAGE**

[image: New Page]

**EDIT PAGE**

[image: EDIT PAGE]

Comment: But what does RecordTypeId show? I don't think Visualforce can automatically query relationships until there's something to query.

Comment: In Apex it debugs as Null on New, and 'MyRecordTypeName' on edit.  So sometime after save, the record type is getting set.  I had it on an Controller extension but I just changed it to my controller (took a little work but I thought the extension may be the issue)

Comment: Where is your new page being generated from?  It appears to be an override, are you overriding a standard button, or navigating to this page elsewhere.  Are more than 1 record types available for your object, and how is it supposed to know what record type to show on the new?

Comment: there is only 1 record type available so by default that selection screen is overidden.  I need to assign the record type in the constructor of the controller for an overridden visualforce page.  That allows my picklists to update properly on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On new, if there is no record type specified, it will save with the default record type AFTER save, but not during the record initialize.  If you are creating the new record in your controller, you are going to have to set the record type, either by query string or in your controller.  The edit page will have the record type because the record has already been saved with the default record type.

Comment: This worked!  I assigned the recordtype in the constructor and the picklists adhered on NEW and (obviously) on EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

The default record type is assigned when you do the DML operation. Thus the instance of record you are showing in the Visualforce page doesn't have a Record Type.

A quickfix would be , to save the default Record Type in hierarchical custom settings and add an If clause in VF.

```
IF New
   Show RecordType from Custom Setting
Else
   Show RecordType From The Record
```